# Twilio SMS webhook parameter for threading

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

I want to look at the posted HTTP parameters to my Messaging Webhook and figure out which sent SMS is being responded to. I have the SID of the SMS I sent, but it doesn't appear in any of the posted parameters. Here are the parameters I see, serialized into a string in URI format:

`ToCountry=US&ToState=CA&SmsMessageSid=SMxxxxxxx&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&FromZip=94080&SmsSid=SMxxxxxxx&FromState=CA&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=MOUNTAIN VIEW&Body=Yeah? &FromCountry=US&To=+1NNNNNNNNNN&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=SMxxxxxxx&AccountSid=ACzzzzzz&From=+1MMMMMMMMMM&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&`

All the values of `SMxxxxxxx` are the same in the POST call.

Am I supposed to make another API call to ask if a specific sent SMS received responses?

Comment: i think no when ever you POST sms it will send you a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post on tracking conversations with SMS seems like it could help you here. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html

```
@app.route("/sms")
def sms():

    #get the cookie value, or default to zero
    messagecount = int(request.cookies.get('messagecount',0))
    messagecount += 1

    twml = twiml.Response()
    twml.sms("You've sent " + str(messagecount) + " messages in this conversation so far")

    resp = make_response(str(twml))

    expires=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=4)
    resp.set_cookie('messagecount',value=str(messagecount),expires=expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))

    return resp
```

Modifying the example there, you can use cookies to track [specific messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message).